# Send all data from SQLite in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

I'm new with SQLite and Node.js and so far the application is able to send some data to the front-end. The problem is that it sends only the first row from the table and it should send all the data.

This is the code so far:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var db = new sqlite3.Database('./db/my_db.db');

router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  db.serialize(function () {
    db.each('SELECT id, name, surname FROM Customers', function (
      err,
      row
    ) {
      res.send(row);
    });
  });

  db.close();
});

module.exports = router;
```

It seems that isn't enough to insert `res.send()` inside `db.each()` because it does the sending only for the first column.

How can it be done for all the data from that table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is related to `db.each()` and `res.send()` because the later one is called only once, sends the response and closes, doesn't go in a loop for all the rows.

The simplest solution in this case is to use `db.all()` instead.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var db = new sqlite3.Database('./db/my_db.db');

router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  db.serialize(function () {
    db.all('SELECT id, name, surname FROM Customers', function (
      err,
      row
    ) {
      res.send(row);
    });
  });

  db.close();
});

module.exports = router;
```